# How to expand/"preprocess" C++ template code

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

To properly debug complex macros in C++ I usually run the preprocessor on them in order to see exactly what the resulting code looks like.

Is there a similar way to "preprocess" template code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way (compiler-dependent) is to use dumping after each compiler step. I wrote a small program:

```
template<class T>
T square(T n)
{
    return n * n;
}

int main(void)
{
    square<int>(3);
    square<float>(3.0);
}
```

then:

```
g++ -fdump-rtl-all test.cc
```

This get me a bunch of files. Take a look at (in my case) test.cc.218.dfinish:

```
;; Function int main() (main)
;; Function T square(T) [with T = int] (_Z6squareIiET_S0_)
;; Function T square(T) [with T = float] (_Z6squareIfET_S0_)
```

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a similar switch for the Visual Studio compilers?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use [Visual C++ Code Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t41260xs.aspx). Don't know if this can help you

Comment: GCC compiles `src` => [GENERIC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html) => [GIMPLE](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) => [RTL](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html) => `asm`. To dump GENERIC/GIMPLE use `-fdump-tree-...` ([GENERIC trees from C/C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/C-and-C_002b_002b-Trees.html) use syntax similar to the source language). More info at [GCC Manual Section on Debugging Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) and the [GCC Internals Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/index.html#Top).

Comment: @maverik, when it comes to a class, not a function, will this way still work?

Answer (score 8):

The CLang compiler features an option `-emit-ast` which dumps the Abstract Syntax Tree used to represent the parsed language. The various instantiations of the template will be represented.

The AST is represented both in memory and in xml version, so you can:

- just use the XML output
- parse it, then produce some C++ code
- create a Rewriter tool (supported directly in CLang) and consume the AST itself

For most code inspections (including checking the overloads selected) I have found that actually reading the XML output (well, grepping through it) was sufficient for my needs.

Comment: removed hedging :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly old question, but I think there has been significant improvements in this area that are not so widely known (yet).

[Metashell](http://metashell.org/) can be used like a sort of gdb for template instantiations. This (as far as I know) builds on clang tooling.

[image]