# Preprocessor stringification macro doesn't work

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am having a problem getting this COMPARE macro to work.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Its a bit of an artificial sample - I wanted to make it as small as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

enum rqtypes {Unknown, Monitor, Query, Snapshot };

class base {
public:
   base() : type(Unknown) {}
   rqtypes type;
};

class CBMonitorDeviceRequest : public base
{
public:
   CBMonitorDeviceRequest() : dn(0) {}
   char* dn;
};


//I want the equivalent of:
//        case MonitorDeviceRequestID:
//           CBMonitorDeviceRequest* pthis = static_cast<CBMonitorDeviceRequest*>(thisrq);
//           if(pthis && strcmp(pthis->dn1, "1234") == 0)
//              return 0;
//           else
//              return -1;
//           break;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   CBMonitorDeviceRequest* ptr = new CBMonitorDeviceRequest;
   ptr->type = Monitor;
   ptr->dn = new char(strlen("1234") + 1);
   strcpy(ptr->dn, "1234");

#define COMPARE(id, thismsg) case id##ID: { \
   CB##id * pthis = static_cast<CB##id *>(thismsg); \
   if(pthis && strcmp(pthis->dn, "1234") == 0) \
      std::cout << "found"; \
   else \
      std::cout << "not found"; \
     break;  } \

   switch(ptr->type){
      COMPARE(Monitor, ptr);
   }

#undef COMPARE

    return 0;
}
```

I get eg:

```
(46) : error C2065: 'MonitorID' : undeclared identifier
(46) : error C2051: case expression not constant
(46) : error C2065: 'CBMonitor' : undeclared identifier
(46) : error C2065: 'pthis' : undeclared identifier
(46) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CBMonitor'
(46) : error C2065: 'pthis' : undeclared identifier
(46) : error C2065: 'pthis' : undeclared identifier
(46) : error C2227: left of '->dn' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Using gcc -E I get:
    # 30 "macro_fun2.cpp"
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
       CBMonitorDeviceRequest* ptr = new CBMonitorDeviceRequest;
       ptr->type = Monitor;
       ptr->dn = new char(strlen("1234") + 1);
       strcpy(ptr->dn, "1234");
    # 45 "macro_fun2.cpp"
       switch(ptr->type){
          case MonitorID: { CBMonitor * pthis = static_cast(ptr); if(pthis && strcmp(pthis->dn, "1234") == 0) Monitor = Query; else Monitor = Snapshot;
     break; };
   }

return 0;
}

```
*** By the way I changed code to to avoid the massive printing of iostream by preprocessor - otherwise -E printing would have been huge.

#define COMPARE(id, thismsg) case id##ID: { \
   CB##id * pthis = static_cast<CB##id *>(thismsg); \
   if(pthis && strcmp(pthis->dn, "1234") == 0) \
      id = Query; \
   else \
      id =  Snapshot; \
     break;  } \
```

Comment: First thing, the stringification operator is a single `#`, and it doesn't appear anywhere in this code.

Comment: What I would suggest you do first, is preprocess the output only, to see what is happening. If you're using GCC this can be done with the -E option. If you're still having trouble with the why, paste the preprocessed output here too and let us know. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options

Comment: @Salgar Any idea how to do that in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Never done it before, but it seems possible in VS2k5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461093/viewing-compiler-expanded-code-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id##ID` will expand to `MonitorID`, which isn't defined. You either want to rename `Monitor` to `MonitorID` in the definition of `rqtypes`, or change this to just `id`.

`CB##id` will expand to `CBMonitor`, which also isn't defined. You either want to rename `class CBMonitorDeviceRequest` to `class CBMonitor`, or change this to `CB##id##DeviceRequest`.

Apart from that, I can't see any obvious problems. Apart from the memory leak, of course. Why aren't you using `std::string` for your strings?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `CB##id`, not `CBid##`.

Comment: Thanks.  I also have the errors I just added however.